# Minikube with Virtualbox or KVM using lots of CPU on Centos 7

Tags: virtualbox, kvm, minikube

I've installed minikube as per the kubernetes instructions.
After starting it, and waiting a while, I noticed that it is using a lot of CPU, even though I have nothing particular running in it.

`top` shows this:

```
%Cpu(s):  0.3 us,  7.1 sy,  0.5 ni, 92.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 32521856 total,  2259992 free,  9882020 used, 20379844 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  2097144 total,   616108 free,  1481036 used. 20583844 avail Mem 

 PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                     
4847 root      20   0 3741112  91216  37492 S  52.5  0.3   9:57.15 VBoxHeadless
```

`lscpu` shows this:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             AuthenticAMD
CPU family:            21
Model:                 2
Model name:            AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 3365
```

I see the same effect if I use KVM instead of VirtualBox

```
kubectl get services

NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   20m
```

I installed metrics-server and it outputs this:

```
kubectl top node minikube

NAME       CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%   
minikube   334m         16%    1378Mi          76%

kubectl top pods --all-namespaces

NAMESPACE                NAME                                    CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)   
default                  hello-minikube-56cdb79778-rkdc2         0m           3Mi             
kafka-data-consistency   zookeeper-84fb4cd6f6-sg7rf              1m           36Mi            
kube-system              coredns-fb8b8dccf-2nrl4                 4m           15Mi            
kube-system              coredns-fb8b8dccf-g6llp                 4m           8Mi             
kube-system              etcd-minikube                           38m          41Mi            
kube-system              kube-addon-manager-minikube             31m          6Mi             
kube-system              kube-apiserver-minikube                 59m          186Mi           
kube-system              kube-controller-manager-minikube        22m          41Mi            
kube-system              kube-proxy-m2fdb                        2m           17Mi            
kube-system              kube-scheduler-minikube                 2m           11Mi            
kube-system              kubernetes-dashboard-79dd6bfc48-7l887   1m           25Mi            
kube-system              metrics-server-cfb4b47f6-q64fb          2m           13Mi            
kube-system              storage-provisioner                     0m           23Mi
```

Questions:

1) is it possible to find out why it is using so much CPU? (note that I am generating no load, and none of my containers are processing any data)

2) is that normal?

Comment: You can run the commands `kubectl top node <node-name>` and `kubectl top pod <pod-name> --containers` to see more detailed metrics.

Comment: `kubectl top node minikube` works. but I don't have any pods running, which is why it's so crazy that so much CPU is being used.

Comment: Hi! Did you found any solution?

Comment: P.S. If someone's interested, I have noticed that Minikube is incapable of running normally on more than 2-4 cores, it seems to be a horribly unoptimized software with livelocks, it eats 40% of resources in idle mode and starts several times slower if I give it more CPUs(6,7.. on my 12 core desktop)

Comment: Minikube improved its performances in 2020, but [the main source of hogging is the *apiserver* and *etcd* implementation of Kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/48948#issuecomment-625049243). There is still no solution that I am aware of, at the current date.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure nothing is running? What happens if you type `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`? By default Kubernetes only displays the pods that are inside the default namespace (thus excluding the pods inside the system namespace).

Also, while I am no CPU expert, this seems like a reasonable consumption for the hardware you have.

Comment: OK @alassane-ndiaye, true, there is the kube-system stuff too - I updated the post with the new info. Note though that I am generating no load, and none of my containers are processing any data, so it's weird to say that minikube should be hogging so much CPU. What is it doing?

Comment: It has to orchestrate all the containers which is no easy task. As you can see, there are many components necessary to make kubernetes function to a bare minimum like the API server, the etcd storage, the various managers and so on. In general, highly distributed systems must do a lot of work in order to make sure the systems remain consistent and highly available, which makes them use more resources than monolithic systems.

Comment: I am no expert on the kubernetes internal either :P

Comment: Hi you should verify why there is o big SWAP space. You can also change minikube parameters during start: minikube start --v=10 --cpus 4 --memory 8192.
Please consider also and disable swap.

Answer (score 1):

In response to question 1):

You can `ssh` into minikube and from there you can run `top` to see the processes which are running:

```
minikube ssh
top
```

There is a lot of docker and kublet stuff running:

```
top - 21:43:10 up  8:27,  1 user,  load average: 10.98, 12.00, 11.46
Tasks: 148 total,   1 running, 147 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu0  :  15.7/15.7   31[||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||                                                                    ]
%Cpu1  :   6.0/10.0   16[||||||||||||||||                                                                                    ]
GiB Mem : 92.2/1.9      [                                                                                                    ]
GiB Swap:  0.0/0.0      [                                                                                                    ]

11842 docker    20   0   24.5m   3.1m   0.7   0.2   0:00.71 R                  `- top                                                                                           
 1948 root      20   0  480.2m  77.0m   8.6   4.1  27:45.44 S  `- /usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --tlsverify --tlscacert /etc/docker/ca+ 
...
 3176 root      20   0   10.1g  48.4m   2.0   2.6  17:45.61 S              `- etcd --advertise-client-urls=https://192.168.39.197:2379 --cert-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/etc+
```

The two process with 27 and 17 hours of processor time are the culprits.

In response to question 2): No idea but could be. See answer from @alassane-ndiaye